# Python Websocket server errors when sending messages

Tags: python, websocket, server

Can anyone help me with my python WebSockets server for some reason whenever I try to send JSON data there are many errors, here is a link to my code:

http://textuploader.com/v5kn

My Client hasn't changed since the last update and doesn't send anything after connection to the server so it should be fine.

Heres the error:

```
connection established ('127.0.0.1', 51777)
Handshaking...
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51429)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:/Users/Heslop/Desktop/Projects/SnakeServer/server.py", line 64, in handle
    self.read_next_message()
  File "C:/Users/Heslop/Desktop/Projects/SnakeServer/server.py", line 68, in read_next_message
    length = ord(self.rfile.read(2)[1]) & 127
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: seems like your server side code has some problems to decode the msg client has sent.

Comment: Yeah thats what I figured! I have no idea I think its my javascript now causing the problems how can I send a string like "SWITCHDIR 0" because right now Im doing it like ws.send("SWITCHDIR 0") but I am starting to think its not right.

Comment: In fact you can try the third-lib for msg encoding and decoding for you, so you can focus on app-building. Here is my:https://github.com/HelloLyfing/py-websocket-helper, if you got any problems, let me know.

Comment: Note that `read(2)` does not mean "*read exactly two bytes*" but *read **no more than** two bytes*. This is especially true for network IO, where `read()` returns as soon as there is *any* data available, even a single byte.

Comment: lyfing - can you post this as a answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can try the third-lib for ServerSide-ClientSide msg(`frame`) encoding and decoding for you, so you can focus on app-building.

Here is my little wrapping for it: https://github.com/HelloLyfing/py-websocket-helper

Since I am the only one who ever used this wrapper, so if you got any problems, please let me know.